# Rails user posting gem with a votable feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby on Rails newbie here. I'm creating an application
where a user can post anything they want and
users can upvote or downvote a user's post. (Reddit alike feature.)
Is there such "posting" gem? I looked into Disqus and seems interesting.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like way to specific a question for something like StackOverflow. I can google this in less time: https://www.google.com/#q=upvote+downvote+rails. First result is the answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the 'acts_as_votable' gem:
https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

You can do stuff like:

```
@post.liked_by @user1
@post.downvote_from @user2
@post.vote_by :voter => @user3
@post.vote_by :voter => @user4, :vote => 'bad'
@post.vote_by :voter => @user5, :vote => 'like'
```